# Want to install new DDR1 RAM. Will this work?

Tags: installation, memory, ddr

CPU-Z reads Currently Installed Memory as:

DDR 512 MB PC3200 (200 MHZ)
DRAM Frequency : 133.4 MHZ
FSB : DRAM : 1:1

Mainboard supports upto 2 memory sticks each of 1 GB.

I recently bought DDR1 512MB Ram which reads 512MB DDR 400 DIMM 2.5-3-3. If I put the newly bought RAM in the 2nd slot will both the memory sticks work fine or will it cause a problem??

Answer (score 3):

DDR-400 and PC3200 are different names for the same RAM, so this should work fine.

DDR-400 comes in three different flavors, A, B and C, to do with the timings.  Your new stick is 2.5-3-3 which is DDR-400A.  It is very likely that your existing ram has the same timings.

If you see any stability issues, then the worst case is you have to remove the RAM, you won't do any damage to your system.